# Eclipse: Can not find class (java) also Mule ESB

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, mule, esb

I am only vaguely familiar with Eclipse.

In the IDE, I switch to the "Driver Name Class Browser", it looks something like

```
                             ___________________________   _________
Driver name classs browser: |                           |  |  ...  |
                            |___________________________|  |_______|
```

So I click the button on the right with the three dots "...", and go to a screen that looks something like:

```
Select Entries:
 ______________________________________________________
|______________________________________________________|

Match Items:
 ______________________________________________________
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|______________________________________________________|
```

So I experiment, asn as I put wildcards in the 'entries box', Java classes will magically appear in the "Matching items' box.  This is all good.

On some of the entries, just the class name appears, but on others the class name AND its source jar file appear.

Now to my point.  I am trying to add the following class

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

However, Eclipse says it cant find it.  So I am guessing I have to add a path or something

The two files I need Eclipse to see are

```
db2jcc.jar  
db2jcc_license_cu.jar
```

and they are contains ed the (Windows) directory of

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java
```

My Questions is How can I add these files to the Eclipse environment so that it can see the classes contained within the jars.

- What path do I take
- How do I format the entry (I need it to see both jars)
- Do I have to re-IPL Eclipse ?

Thanks

BTW, I am running Mule ESB flavor of Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the classpath in java using Eclipse IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144258/setting-the-classpath-in-java-using-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a User Library from the menu path:

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path => User Libraries
```

You hit NEW, and add a name, then you hit ADD EXTERNAL JARS, and add the jar

Then you add the new User Library to the build path of your project

```
  - Rt click on test1
  - click on Properties
  - Click on "Java Build Path"
  - Check "TEST_LIB"
```