# chromedriver not instantiating in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following code to try to create a Java program (in Eclipse Neon) that uses Selenium. I have tried a whole bunch of different combinations of backslashes and forwards slashes like "C://Users/talai/..." and "C:\Users\talai" etc. but nothing is working.

Below is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for(int d=0; d<20; d++)//run program d<___ times
    {
        //One "Play" session = 5m 15s
        //One "Collect" session = ???
        System.out.println("Session " +d+ " of 300 starting...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users/talai/Desktop/code/ChipCollector/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And this is the output:

```
Session 0 of 300 starting...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at myVegas.Run.main(Run.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

A few words :

- As per best practices you shouldn't open **20** *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances at a time without any proper *usecase* and availability of proper hardware. So you need to remove the `for()` loop as in :

  ```
  for(int d=0; d<20; d++)
  ```
- *System Paths* in *Java* are expressed either through double back slashes (`\\`) or single forward slash (`/`). Both works identically.
- The error you are seeing says it all :

  ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
       at myVegas.Run.main(Run.java:44)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
  ```

The error implies that **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** was raised which was caused by **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**.

---

### What is **`NoClassDefFoundError`**

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** in Java occurs when **`Java Virtual Machine`** is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. For example, if we have resolved a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that Class is not available during run-time then **`JVM`** will throw **`NoClassDefFoundError`**.

This clearly indicates that *Selenium* is trying to resolve the **ChromeDriver** class at runtime from **import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;** which is no more available.

---

### What went wrong :

From the above mentioned points it's clear that the related `Class` or `Methods` were resolved from one source `Compile Time` which was not available during `Run Time`.

This situation occurs if there are presence of multiple sources to resolve the `Classes` and `Methods` as :

- Presence of **selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1** *JAR* and *JARs* from **selenium-java-3.9.1** within your *Project Space*.
- Presence of **selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1** *JAR* and **Maven** related *JARs*.
- Presence of **selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1** *JAR* and **Gradle** related *JARs*.

---

### Solution :

Here are a few steps to solve **`NoClassDefFoundError`** :

- Use either **selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1** *JAR* or  *JARs* from **selenium-java-3.9.1**
- If using a Build Tool e.g. **Maven** or **Gradle**, **remove** all the **External JARs** from the *Java Build Path*. **Maven** or **Gradle** will download and resolve all the required dependencies.
- If using *Selenium JARs* within a *Java Project* add only required *External JARs* within the *Java Build Path* and remove the unused one.
- While using *Maven*, either use **`<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>`** or **`<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`**. Avoid using both at the same time.
- Remove the unwanted other **`<dependency>`** from **`pom.xml`**
- Clean you *Project Workspace* within your IDE regularly only to build your project with required dependencies.
- Use [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe away the OS chores periodically.
- While you execute a *Maven Project* always do **`maven clean`**, **`maven install`** and then **`maven test`**
- If your *Web Browser* base version is too old uninstall the *Web Browser* through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA released version of the *Web Browser*.

Answer (score 0):

Your JRE can't find a class. It can't find the class com.google.common.base.Function, because you didn't added it to class path.

Just add appropriate Selenium Standalone as per suited version by you in your [project class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144258/setting-the-classpath-in-java-using-eclipse-ide) simple. It should do it.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried adding it to the build path by right clicking on my project, then build path but that didn't work. I also followed the link you sent which suggested adding a user library. I added the selenium files and clicked "apply" but am still getting the same problem

Comment: Okay that means Selenium requires guava library to be in classpath. Use th link for configuring with class path : https://github.com/google/guava.