# How to import a java class from a folder outside src into a package located in src?

Tags: java, eclipse

So, I have this project I am currently trying to fix just for personal reasons.

In some of my classes it imports a java file from a folder to a package inside the src folder. The folders are located outside the src folder but I need it to stay like that. So how would I be able to import a java file from inside a folder (Which is located outside the src) into another java file (Located inside the source)?

[Trying to import a file from the toolbox into the collision detection packcage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXaf.jpg)

I moved the actual folder into the src file but that is not what I am really intending to do. I need the folder to stay inside where it is currently right now incase I dont mess up anything.

Please try and give the simplest answer possible so I can understand and try to answer the question rather than telling me to do other things.

Thanks

Comment: What command(s) or tool(s) are you using to compile and run your project?

Comment: I'm using eclipse to compile and run. I only need to import from the folder to the package class.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you please add a scribble (preferrably a nested bulletpoint list or similar) of your folder structure and use the folder / file names in your question to give us a better idea of your problem? Also: the java file from "imports a java file from a folder to a package inside the src folder." is java sourcecode that you want to use in your project to call methods? Or is it just "data" (can also be java source but as pure text file) you want to access?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is import a java file from the toolbox folder( which is located outside the src folder) and import it into a class inside the collsion detection package. Is this possible? Reason why I won't make it into a package is because i got the java project sent to me that way and that is the way the person who sent it to me set up there project.

Comment: If you mean to use the Java `import` statement, you have to add the folder to your project classpath - I think this still works as described in this other SO question [Setting the classpath in Java using Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144258/setting-the-classpath-in-java-using-eclipse-ide)

Comment: OK I just did that but it didn't work and it just created errors epic render engine. I have a folder inside the epic render engine acts as a package but its outside the src. So I think my problem is that I'm trying to import a java class which is outside the src. I tried what you just said but it didn't work even though I specified which folder it was that I needed. If anyone else knows how to fix this just drop a message below

Comment: you have to setup a proper build system here. If you want to use external source code as library, you have to build that first into a JAR file, and only then you can use it in your project. Everything else will result in a big mess.

Comment: Could you maybe link an YouTube video or online tutorial on that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use "foreign" source code that is shipped as a "bundle", this is probably a library that you should compile on it's own, package into one or more JAR-files and then depend on them in your project so they will be included in your classpath.

You really should setup a proper build system to build the 3rd party library and also to build your own program.
Common build tools include Maven (https://maven.apache.org/) which is mature and widely supported in the world of java, and also Gradle (https://gradle.org/) which is more modern and the "primary supported" (by Google) build system for Android Apps.

Looking at the screenshot of your code, it could be possible that you want to use the EpicRenderEngine from github (https://github.com/SkyWorld117/EpicRenderEngine/tree/main).

It has a ready made build file for Gradle (*build.gradle*), so I would recommend that you use Gradle also for your own project, just so you don't have to learn and install two build systems at once.

(Maven builds typically have one or more files called *pom.xml*, just in case...)

There are plugins for Eclipse to support Gradle (https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) and also a plugin for Gradle to support eclipse (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html).

Usually you set up a build system so the build runs smooth even when started from the command line. This ensures independence from your IDE - IDEs also support the popular build systems very good and so usually you don't have to use the commandline to build your software - but for sharing code among multiple developers, it's always easier if every dev can use the personal favoured IDE instead of an IDE that's dictated by the project.

To get more info about Gradle or Maven, go to their homepages, both have a lot docs to get started and to get deeper into the topic if you want to.

(I'm not used to watch developer docs as videos, so I don't have any advice there that I could pull out of my sleeve, and to send you just some search results doesn't seem useful to me...)